# MongoDB Spring Data Projection Returns only the First Matched Element

Tags: java, mongodb, spring-data-mongodb, mongorepository

I have

```
@Document
public class Employee
{
 @Id
 Long empCode;
 String empSurname;
 String address;
// getters setters
}
```

Then I have an extension of the MongoRepository

```
public interface EmployeeRepository extends MongoRepository<Employee, Long>
{
  EmployeeProject findAddressByEmpSurname(String surName);
}
```

EmployeeProject is a Projection

```
public interface EmployeeProject 
{
    public List<String> getAddress();
}
```

I am calling

```
EmployeeProject param = employeeRepository.findAddressByEmpSurname("Smith");
param.getAddress().size(); -> Returns the first matched element only
```

I need getAddress() to return all matched values as a String and not just the first one.

Any help would be much appreciated. Thanks.
PS: If I run the generated query directly on the MongoDB database, I get back all documents.
It appears that I need a [Collection Projection](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/4.2.5.RELEASE/spring-framework-reference/html/expressions.html) but I can't seem to get the Syntax correct.

Comment: I guess due to EmployeeProject  it is firing findOne query.. Just use List<String> instead of EmployeeProject..

Comment: Tried it. No luck.

Comment: Strange 
List<String> findAddressByEmpSurname(String surName); works for me. 
Try putting this entry in log file.. It will help u knw what query is being fired.
log4j.logger.org.springframework.data.mongodb=debug